# nbdev-tutorial: nbdev_build_docs & Github Pages not working properly

Tags: python, html, github, jupyter-notebook

Good evening,

following the nbdev tutorial ([Klick](https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorial.html)) from scratch i could not get the hosted documentation to look nice. Also the link to an exisiting module is missing.

Github pages output:

[image]

Github repo that stores this project:
([Klick](https://github.com/SimiPixel/mat2np))

The weird thing is that everything works just fine (no errors), still the rendered Github page looks much nicer in the tutorial.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior, did you find a solution?

Comment: No sorry. I gave up on the idea.